# SHELL монитор на JS

Tags: php, javascript, linux, shell

Есть приложение которое отправляет в бек разного типа задачки , эти задачки набиваются в очередь и каждые 15 минут `cron` их выполняет. На данный момент есть простое уведомление что крон начал обработку очереди задачек , все ок работает . Появилось желание слушать состояние выполнения, конечно можно почитать лог но хочется real-time из браузера.

Ход мыслей :

1. Отправляем задачку в бэк.
2. Пишем ее в лог типа : `php run.php AmoParser mode=base_state > AmoParser_thread_$thread`
3. На клиенте каждые 5 сек отправляем `AJAX` и читаем лог задачки

Тут как бы все понятно , читаем лог - транслируем в браузер , по завершению в лог отправить какойто флаг , что трансляция кончилась (или как?). 
Но вот как быть если одновременно выполняется 10 задачек , хотелось бы как то смотреть состояние всех.

Как быть если лог очень большой или задачка выполняется медленно? если я буду все транслировать в браузер он так или иначе упадет со временем, надо как то контролировать выдачу и как то организовывать постепенный стриминг файла лога .

что посоветуете?

Comment: Как вариант в браузере показывать только кусок лога. А по поводу того как остановить трансляцию, можно сделать условие по таймауту отсутствия новых данных.

Comment: Отсутствие новых данных за какой период? а если данных нет но задачка выполняется? можно конечно проверять `PID` . Кусок лога в смысле последние 200 строк? типа `cat <log_file> | tail -200`

Answer (score 1):

В общем не дождался я ответа и решил задачку как знал , расписывать код не буду опишу логику.

1. Когда пользователь нажимает кнопку запуска джоба, происходит ajax запрос , который обращается к контроллеру запуска джоба, в параметрах передается timestamp запуска , модель запускает задачку в бек и начинает писать лог действий с именем параметра timestamp . Назад пользователю уходит ответ , что джоб с запущен и pid процесса которой пишет лог
2. Этот ответ инициализирует таймер которые каждые 2 сек отправляет запрос с параметром названия лога и смещением относительно позиции с которой читать лог. 
   назад получает ответ с текстом лога и размером лога, размер лога при следующем запросе является параметров смещения (offset) , таким образом я всегда получаю свежую порцию куска лога а не весь лог.
3. При каждом запросе сохраняю размер лога и сравниваю его с пред идущим , если размер отличается добовляю ответ к выдаче, если не отличается то проверяю состояние PID , если его нет то вывожу собщение что процесс отработал.

Таким образом я получаю рабочий монитор для состояния джоба без надобности читать выдочу с почты или читать лог на сервере. Получился достаточно симпатичный и удобный монитор :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте использовал БД. Таблица с 4-мя полями: id_job, timestamp, text, status

Comment: Угу, я тоже об этому думал , скорее всего так и сделаю.

Comment: Вот еще посмотрите https://www.sitepoint.com/php-streaming-output-buffering-explained/